# mysqli_num_rows() - Is not working

Tags: php, sql, ajax, json

I have a form that takes a users email and password & also have script that creates a JSON object and sends that object that encapsulates the password and email to the server using AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var email, password;

    $('#submit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        email = $('#email').val();
        password = $('#password').val();

        $memberData = {
            'email' : email,
            'password':password
        };
        $memberData = JSON.stringify($memberData);

        login();
    });

    function login()
    {  
        $.ajax({
            url: 'scripts/processLogin.php',
            data: 'json='+ $memberData,
            success: function(result){
                var r = JSON.parse(result);
                alert(r.result); 
            }
        });
    }
});

Then in my processLogin.php I have:

include 'dbConnect.php';
    $jsonS = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'json'); //get object sent to file
    $memberData = json_decode(stripslashes($jsonS)); //convert JSON object to string
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($memberData->email);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($memberData->password); 
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `password` = '$password'");

   $rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
   if($rows > 0){ 
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email; 
        $result = "Successfully Logged in"; 
   } else {
       $result = "Invalid Login Credentials";    
   } 
    $result = array("result"=>$result);
    echo json_encode($result);
```

here is dbConnect.php:

```
<?php
    $dbLocation = "localhost";
    $dbName="database"; 
    $dbUsername="root";
    $dbPassword = "root";
    $connect = mysqli_connect($dbLocation,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName) 
        or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysqli_select_db($connect,$dbName)
        or die("cannot select DB");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
?>
```

When I run this it does not alert at all. I tried debugging by adding line by line in the proccessLogin.php (noob way) and assigned a normal string to $result(testing sake) and it would alert until I added : $rows = mysql_num_rows($query), I tried using mysqli_num_rows() but it also did not work. I know in my dbConnect I use mysqli, but if i use that with my query it does not work , it also does not work if I use  mysqli_real_escape_string()
Any help will be appreciated. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `mysqli_connect`, `mysql_query` What library do you really use?

Comment: You know that sending user data from javascript to php is not reliable. People can turn of theire javascript and your complete login / register will fail

Answer (score 0):

I dont really sure I understand the problem but give it a shot.

replace this:

```
 $connect = mysqli_connect($dbLocation,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);
```

with this:

```
 $connect = new mysqli($dbLocation,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);
```

and this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `password` = '$password'");

$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

with this:

```
$query = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `password` = '$password'");

$rows = $query->num_rows;
```

Comment: That fixed it, thank you. So if now I wanted to get the the row of data from the database to store it in the SESSION array how would i do that? $data = $query->fetch_array;

Comment: Like that: `$data = $query->fetch_array();`. You should read about mysqli. http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php